# Adding Temporary drawer function in Mini variant drawer from Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I am using Mini variant drawer from Material UI and its working fine but in this drawer when I open the nav bar and click anywhere outside the nav bar, it isn't closing. Just like in Temporary drawer. I tried to implement but failed.

Mini variant drawer

https://codesandbox.io/s/6xdsb?file=/index.js

Temporary drawer

https://codesandbox.io/s/ktmju

Any help would be really appriciated.

Comment: both the components act differently. In the drawer, the overlay supports the click to dismiss it. In case of the mini drawer, either provide a supporting overlay so as to attach an event and when the user clicks there you can fire the hide drawer action.

Answer (score 1):

The Mini Variant is a Persistent Drawer, and from the Material UI website:

> Persistent navigation drawers can toggle open or closed. The drawer
>   sits on the same surface elevation as the content. It is closed by
>   default and opens by selecting the menu icon, ***and stays open until
>   closed by the user.***

So it is not meant to be closed when the user clicks outside of it.

Although I'm not sure why you want to implement this functionality with a persistent drawer but maybe this Material UI util will help you

[Material UI Click Away Listener](https://material-ui.com/components/click-away-listener/)

Comment: I need that kind of UI with that option and ya I tried Click Away Listener but its acting weird.

Comment: How is it acting exactly? Can you explain so maybe I can help you?